# Error on Tcl version 8.6.9 Package Profiler Error (package ifneeded profiler)

Tags: package, tcl, profiler

I have been seeing this error when running Tcl scripts on Tcl version 8.6.9:

```
attempt to provide package profiler 0.4 failed: package profiler 0.5 provided instead
("package ifneeded profiler 0.4" script)
invoked from within
"package require profiler"
```

And the code stops after this - could anyone guide me please?

tried re-installing Tcl, checked my task manager, also checked if all libraries had been installed properly - everything looks ok. However I have still been getting the same error. I even checked the file directories the error had been pointing me towards - but still no luck.

Comment: I think you have a version difference between the `pkgIndex.tcl` file and the `profiler.tcl` file. Have a look at the 2 files to see if the version on the `package ifneeded` line is different from the `package provide` version. But why , I don’t know.